# FileNotFoundError while copying files into a directory

Tags: python, shutil

I've a text file "Flickr_8k.testImages.txt" that contains filenames of 1000 files separated by new line. These files are inside the directory 'Flickr8k_Dataset' which contains 8000+ files. All I want to do is, copy the files that are listed in the text file into a separate directory 'dstn' which is located in same path where this script is.
On executing this script it shows following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sbs/Documents/new_script/copy_images.py", line 13, in <module>
copy(filename, dstn)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 241, in copy
copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '3385593926_d3e9c21170.jpg'
```

This is my script.

```
import os
from shutil import copy2
scriptpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
f1 = open("Flickr_8k.testImages.txt", 'r') #this file contains filenames
directory = os.path.join(scriptpath, 'Flickr8k_Dataset') #'Flickr8k_Dataset' this directory contains files
dstn = os.path.join(scriptpath, 'dstn')
count = 0
for line in f1.read().split("\n"):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if line == filename:
            copy2(filename, dstn)
            print(filename, ' copied.')
            count += 1

print(count, ' files found and copied successfully!')
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you are running? The error message says there was something wrong with the line `copy(filename, dstn)`, but there is no such line in the code you provided.

Comment: @PaxVobiscum I assumed it was just a typo as `copy2(filename, dstn)` exists in the code above and it just has a `2` in it.

Comment: @Adi219 [This import](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) makes me want to think otherwise.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. `copy(filename, dstn)` may be shown because  `copy()` and `copy2()` are very similar functions of shutil.

Comment: @PaxVobiscum Yep, you're right!

Comment: @itssubas It doesn't matter how similar they are, they clearly exists in 2 different places. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/shutil.py#L368

Comment: @PaxVobiscum that is the exact error shown. I figured out `filename` on line 9 didn't hold the correct path earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, you don't have the correct path to the file.

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally figured it out.